# Change the custom button by an other when the user click on it

Tags: ios, uibutton

I try to realize that, when the user click on a button (custom one), it will be changed by another button, to do so, i use the selected property :

[image]

What i notice that the image of the button is changed while the user keep pressing the button, if he releases the button, it returns to his old form, what i need is it still changed sine the user select the button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is only one line of code.

```
[yourButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"select-button.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

Comment: but my button doesn't have a name because it was added directly on Interface builder, what should i put in the place of `yourButton `? thanx

Comment: i try to give it a name with an IBOutlet, and i use your line of code, unfortunately, the button image hasn't been changed.

Answer (score 1):

This is best done programmatically, rather than in Interface Builder. Set up an action for your button such that when it is clicked, the button image changes:

```
- (IBAction)buttonTapped:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *theButton = (UIButton *)sender;
    if ([theButton currentImage] == self.imageOne) {
        [theButton setImage:self.imageTwo forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else {
        [theButton setImage:self.imageOne forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

    // (remaining action code)...
}
```

Comment: You are faster then me =) ok!

Answer (score 0):

I think best way is Use two button in same frame ,When user click Button1,hide button1 and show button2.if user click button2,hide button2 and show button1